# How can i add root path Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-blockui

How can I refer root path in Javascript like:

```
$.blockUI.defaults.growlCSS['background'] = 'url(~/Styles/images/check48.gif) no-repeat 10px 10px #000; ';
```

Comment: A path starting with `/` always refers to the root of your site (not the folder). If you have a `<base>` tag set in HTML, you don't need the first `/`.

Comment: what if i use virtual directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biju was wondering how to solve this in javascript, a way to do it is:

```
var path = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/'; // or whatever you want to set it to
$.blockUI.defaults.growlCSS['background'] = 'url(' + path + 'Styles/images/check48.gif) no-repeat 10px 10px #000; ';
```